# Composite IN clause with NULL value

Tags: mysql

I'm wanting to use the `IN` clause doing a search as it looks cleaner than having loads of `AND` and `OR`s. I will be doing this search using a composite key. So for example I have a table `table1` with two columns: `col1 int(12) NOT NULL` and `col2 varchar(15) NULL`. I use the following query to pull out the data:

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2`
FROM `table1`
WHERE (`col1`, `col2`) IN ((1, "ROW1"), (2, "ROW2"), ...)
```

Since `col2` may contain a `NULL` value I may have a case where I need to do:

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2`
FROM `table1`
WHERE (`col1`, `col2`) IN ((1, "ROW1"), (2, NULL), ...)
```

This query wont throw any errors but it won't pull out the data for `(2, NULL)`. Is there a way for the `IN` clause to accept this type of syntax or will it just be a case of having to add them as separate conditional statements? Such as...

```
SELECT `col1`, `col2`
FROM `table1`
WHERE (`col1`, `col2`) IN ((1, "ROW1"), ...) OR (`col1`=2 AND `col2` IS NULL) OR ...
```

Is there a cleaner way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

though not a good solution but you can try this

```
SELECT 
`col1`, `col2`
FROM 
`table1`
WHERE 
(`col1`, `col2`) IN ((1, "ROW1"), (2, "ROW2")) 
OR 
(`col1` IN (2,4) and col2 is null)
```

Comment: Definitely a lot more cleaner though. I'll see what other people come up with before accepting.